# Validating a mathematical expression in java

Tags: java, regex, validation

I am trying to validate if the string "expression" as in the code below is a formula.

```
 String expression = request.getParameter(FORMULA);
 if(!Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9+-*/()]", expression)){return new AjaxMessage(AjaxMessage.ResponseStatusEnum.FAILURE, getJsonString(, "Manager.invalid.formula" , null));
}
```

examples of value for **expression** are **{a+b/2, (a+b)*2,(john-Max),etc}** just for the context (the variable names in the formula might vary and the arithmetic expression contains only **[+-/()*]** special characters. As you can see I tried to validate using regex (new to regex), but I think it's not possible as I don't know the length of the variable names.

Is there a way to achieve a validation using regex or any other library in java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[+-*]` creates a *range*, and makes your regex invalid. Put the `-` at the end of the character class.

Comment: well, using Regex for such a thing is not a good thing to do. Valid arithmetic expressions are not down to the question "did it only contain certain letters", but more of a semantic thing ( did every parenthesis get closed like such [] () ) and by that is more of a natural language parsing thing. Thats just my humble opinion, see for further details: http://dsp.rice.edu/sites/dsp.rice.edu/files/publications/conference-paper/2015/mlp_0.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You're using special character in your regex, you need to escape them using `\`.
It should look like `[a-zA-Z0-9+\\-*/()]` . This only tests one character you need to add a `*` at the end to test multiple characters.

Edit (thanks Toto): because `[]` tests a single character, it's called a character class (not like a Java class actually), so only the `-`is considered special here. For a regex without the braces, you would neeed to escape the other special characters.

Special characters have special meaning using regex and won't be interpreted as the character they are (for example parenthesis are used to make groups, `*` means 0 or more of the previous character, etc.).

About character class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html

More info:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html and
http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html

I use this site to test my regexes (note that regex engine may vary !):
https://regex101.com/

As said in comment, a mathematic expression is more than just different characters, so if you want to validate, you'll have to do more manual checking.

Comment: In character class, special char don't need to be escaped

Comment: @Toto I don't understand what you're saying, the `Character` wrapper class in Java ? it's not in use here. I've edited because I forgot you need to escape  the \ in Java ...

Comment: OP's regex IS a character class, so there're no needs to escape anything except the `-`

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are using characters with special meaning in regex. You need to escape those characters.  I have just modified yor regex to make it work.

Code:

```
List<String> expressions = new ArrayList<String>();
    expressions.add("a+b/2");
    expressions.add("(a+b)*2");
    expressions.add("john-Max");
    expressions.add("etc[");
    for (String expression : expressions) {
        if (!Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9\\+\\-\\*/\\(\\)]*", expression)) {
            System.out.println("NOT match");
        } else {
            System.out.println("MATCH");
        }
    }

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
MATCH
MATCH
MATCH
NOT match
```

Comment: `+`, `(`, `)` and `*` don't need to be escaped in a character class.

Comment: I did and it is not regarding character class it need to be escaped to accept the given expression as valid Java Regular Expressions. Otherwise exception is thrown.

Comment: Your code will also match "(a++/**-b)*2", which is not a valid mathematical expression

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned I have just modified the regex given. So that it should at least compile and run If needed the person asking question can modify further if any other validations are required.

Comment: Only `-` needs to be escape or put at the begining or at the end of the character class.